# Use one button for both save and edit on Gridview in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a scenario where I can save the name and phone number. but now I want to use my "Save" button as update button from clicking on grid view data.

Also after clicking on gridview data "save" button automatically change as "Update"
I want to know if there is any event or something to make it.

Screenshot of my form:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StoredProcedureExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-S80LS9D;Initial Catalog=ComboBoxTest;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter data;
        DataSet ds;
        int num = 0;
        int i;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UserInformation", conn);
            data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            data.Fill(ds);
            this.userdataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveRecord();
            ShowRecordAfterSaveAndEdit();
            clearfilds();
        }

        public void SaveRecord()
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insertupdate", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (userTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                num = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                num = int.Parse(userTextBox.Text);
            }

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", num);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", phoneNumberTextBox.Text);

            if (saveButton.Text == "Save")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", 'S');
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateUser", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 && saveButton.Text == "Save")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("record inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("record Update");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public void clearfilds()
        {
            userTextBox.Text = "";
            nameTextBox.Text = "";
            phoneNumberTextBox.Text = "";
            saveButton.Text = "Save";
        }

        public void ShowRecordAfterSaveAndEdit()
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UserInformation", conn);
            data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            data.Fill(ds);
            this.userdataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int show = userdataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            userTextBox.Text = userdataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
            nameTextBox.Text = userdataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
            phoneNumberTextBox.Text = userdataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["PhoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to change caption of the button, then change it... no event needed

Comment: I want to know how to change this caption

TIA

Comment: saveButton.Text = "Update";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can create an Update button then place it behind the Save button. Add a `RowHeaderMouseClick` event on your dataGridView that will place the values from the highlighted cells to the textboxes.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            //assuming the datagrid displays ID in the 1st cell, Cells[0]
           string name = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
           string phoneNum = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        textBox2.Text = name;
        textBox3.Text = phoneNum;
        updateButton.BringToFront();
        saveButton.SendToBack(); //optional
    }
```

Then, add these lines to your Update button `Click` event to bring the Save button in front again.

```
saveButton.BringToFront();
updateButton.SendToBack();
```

Comment: Thaxs @C C it works..
Though i solve it with double click event

Answer (score 1):

Make two Event for grid view.

1)Got Focus

2)Lost Focus

1)On **GotFocus** Event Change it to Update and maintain mode to insert and update

2)On **Lost Focus** Change it to Save.